# Count and Sum data in a Pandas dataframe based on criteria within each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am a novice coder and feel like this should be easy to do, but I can't quite wrap my head around it based on other people's questions.

I have a dataframe that contains some horse data, and I am trying to summarize some breeding data.  It is a large dataset, but below is a simple example:

```
   horse_id horse_type  Sire_horse_id  Dam_horse_id  Races
0       101  Stalllion             50            80     20
1       102       Mare             51            81      3
2       103   Stallion             90            70     33
3       104       Colt            101            77     27
4       105      Filly             52           102     17
5       106      Filly            101           102     23
6       107       Mare            103            35     33
7       108       Colt            103            77     18
8       109       Colt            102           107      5
9       110      Filly            101           107     12
```

I want to add a column that looks up the 'Sire_horse_id' and 'Dam_horse_id' columns and counts the number of times that they equal the 'horse_id'.  Once I have counted the number of times that a horse_id appears as a Sire or Dam, I want to sum all of the races that those offspring have competed in.  So I expect it to look something like this:

```
   horse_id  Sire_horse_id  Dam_horse_id  Races  Offspring  Offspring races
0       101             50            80     20          3               62
1       102             51            81      3          3               45
2       103             90            70     33          2               51
3       104            101            77     27          0                0
4       105             52           102     17          0                0
5       106            101           102     23          0                0
6       107            103            35     33          2               17
7       108            103            77     18          0                0
8       109            102           107      5          0                0
9       110            101           107     12          0                0
```

Below is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df  = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\PC\Documents\ZedRun\exampledf.csv')
 
df['Offspring'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(df['Sire_horse_id'] == x.horse_id),axis=1) + df.apply(lambda x: sum(df['Dam_horse_id'] == x.horse_id),axis=1)
df['Offspring Races'] = df.groupby('horse_id')['Races'].apply(lambda x: sum(df['Sire_horse_id'] == 
x.horse_id),axis=1)    

print(df)
```

I can get the count of offspring to work, however it seems very slow in a large dataset, so any advice there would be appreciated.

But I can't figure out how to sum up all of the races that a horses offspring have run in. I get an error saying unexpected keyword argument 'axis'.  And I can't really get clear in my head where to use 'horse_id' and when to use 'Sire_horse_id' / 'Dam_horse_id'.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to stack the Sire horse and Dam_horse then [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation),  [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to match the `horse_id` column and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the initial DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(
    # Stack Sire_horse and Dam_horse on top of each other
    pd.concat([
        df[['horse_id', 'Sire_horse_id', 'Races']],
        df[['horse_id', 'Dam_horse_id', 'Races']].rename(
            columns={'Dam_horse_id': 'Sire_horse_id'}  # Align columns
        )
    ]).groupby('Sire_horse_id').agg(
        # Aggregate into new columns
        Offspring=('horse_id', 'count'),
        Offspring_races=('Races', 'sum')
    ).reindex(df['horse_id'], fill_value=0)  # reindex to match horse_id
        .reset_index(drop=True)  # remove to match DataFrame index
)
```

Or with [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) for both Sire_horse_id and Dam_horse_id [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) together, then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to match the `horse_id` column and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the initial DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(
    # Groupby Sire_horse_id
    df.groupby('Sire_horse_id').agg(
        # Aggregate Sire_horses
        Offspring=('horse_id', 'count'),
        Offspring_races=('Races', 'sum')
    ).reindex(df['horse_id'], fill_value=0)  # Reindex to match df
        .add(  # Add Second Aggregation 
        # Groupby Dam_horses
        df.groupby('Dam_horse_id').agg(
            # Aggregate Dam_horses
            Offspring=('horse_id', 'count'),
            Offspring_races=('Races', 'sum')
        ).reindex(df['horse_id'], fill_value=0)  # Reindex to match df
    )
        .reset_index(drop=True)  # Remove index to match df range index
)
```

`df`:

```
   horse_id horse_type  Sire_horse_id  Dam_horse_id  Races  Offspring  Offspring_races
0       101  Stalllion             50            80     20          3               62
1       102       Mare             51            81      3          3               45
2       103   Stallion             90            70     33          2               51
3       104       Colt            101            77     27          0                0
4       105      Filly             52           102     17          0                0
5       106      Filly            101           102     23          0                0
6       107       Mare            103            35     33          2               17
7       108       Colt            103            77     18          0                0
8       109       Colt            102           107      5          0                0
9       110      Filly            101           107     12          0                0
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, however I get an error 'TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'' when using this code?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Named aggregation is "new" in 0.25.0 (July 18, 2019)

Comment: 0.22.0 so I guess that explains it.  Will update and try again.

Comment: Sounds good. If you're using a 5-year-old version of the library, it's helpful to include that information in the question. Both of these options are written in python 3.9 and pandas 1.3.2. Both of the language and the library have changed significantly since 2017.

Comment: Works fine with Pandas 1.2.1

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks Henry.  Finally updated my packages - hadn't realised how out of date they were!  This solution makes it so easy to include other offspring statistics as well.  Thanks again.